# What's the point of making separate objects in one model?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow, extrude

I was following  [Daniel Kreuter's Anime Character 3D Modeling Tutorial II](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9NTBQja_r2NI5e56PvuSAA)  series. There is a section where instead of extruding the arms and legs, he instead made new objects and patched them in the body. Wouldn't it be better to just extrude the arms and legs instead of making a new object? The series was published 2014 so I'm not expecting an answer right now. I still commented it. I'm planning to use it in an indie game so I'm finding the best approach I can to make the models. I'm still not finished watching the tutorials.

Comment: Do as you pleased. If it's easier for you to model from separated parts do that and if you are more comfortable with extruding parts from base mesh - choose this approach. There is no proper or "properer" way of doing this.

Comment: Modeling limbs separately and pasting them later might be more convenient, it could  mean that you are not moving all of the geometry every single time. If you are working on the toes there is no need to have the head, shoulders and chest getting in the way... The downside of this is keeping track of where the parts connect and plan for proper edge flow once re-attached.

Comment: Separate meshes lets you focus your work and viewport a little more efficiently without other parts getting in the way.

Comment: So does that mean its personal preference? I mean he does that because he wants to focus on a single object? And he also said that it cannot be merged. Does this affect somehow?